# SQL - selecting rows when field is between two columns of other table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have two tables which contain, respectively:

```
| User        | birthday      | 
| ----------- |:-------------:|
| 'you'       | '1980-11-01'  | 
| 'me'        | '1986-12-27'  |
```

and

```
| Event        | date_start   |   date_end   | 
| ------------ |:-------------:|   ------------- | 
| 'e1'         | '1980-10-13'  |   '1980-12-01'
| 'e2'         | '1986-01-04'  |   '1987-01-01'
| 'e3'         | '2000-10-13'  |   '2003-12-01'
```

and suppose for each event in the second table I want to select all users whose birthday falls in between the timespan of their dates, meaning inside the interval between `date_start` and `date_end`.

Obviously a JOIN wouldn't suit this need, is there a way? For reference, I am particularly interested in doing this on a Redshift database.

Comment: An expected result would be good for better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why join is not sufficient?

```
select *
from event e
join user u on e.date_start < u.birthday and e.date_end > u.birthday
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LISTAGG Function

```
select (select istagg(u.User) within group (order by u.User)   
        from user u 
        where 
        u.birthday >=  ev.date_start and u.birthday <  ev.date_end ) 
        from event_table ev
```

Comment: Thanks, have accepted Radim's answer as it seems less heavyweight than window functions though?

Comment: I think so, this is useful if you need to concatenate results in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a solution:

```
SELECT
  ev.name,
  LISTAGG(user_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY user_name DESC ) "Users"
FROM events ev
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.birthday >=  ev.datestart AND u.birthday <= ev.dateend
GROUP BY ev.name;
```